# Trying to show 1 of 2 Dropdownlists on page_load wont work. ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to have 1 of 2 drop down lists show on a page when the page loads based on a session variable. I have tried removing the If statement altogether and still cannot get the lists to show or hide by using Control.Visible = True (or False). What am I doing wrong? Can you not have control properties change in the Page_Load sub?

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Session("Role") = 1 Then
            DropDownList1.Visible = True
            DropDownList2.Visible = False
        Else
            DropDownList2.Visible = True
            DropDownList1.Visible = False
        End If

    End Sub
```

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Utility.aspx.vb" Inherits="Utility.Utility" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<hr />
<div style="height: 16px">
</div>
<body id="PageBody" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="height: 318px">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="18px" Width="339px" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Choice</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="18px" Width="339px" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Choice</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't worked with ASP.NET in a long time, but have you tried the Page_Init event instead?

Comment: like this?: 
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles Me.Init

  If Session("Role") = 1 Then
   DropDownList1.Visible = True
   DropDownList2.Visible = False
  Else
   DropDownList2.Visible = True
   DropDownList1.Visible = False
  End If

 End Sub

Comment: Yes, does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I have added the asp code (removing the list items). do you want/need more than just the control's asp?

Comment: @Austin ok sorry I didnt know about @-ing :). I have added the rest of the surrounding markup I think.

Comment: @Austin only a button that pulls the selected value from the ddl and runs a SQL query based on it.

Comment: @Austin but the weird thing is, if I put ANY control in the Page_Load and try to set it to visible true or false, none of them work. not just the ddls. I tried it with a random label control as well that works with a button press further down the form.

Comment: @Austin NEVERMIND! I think I was only "saving" the forms and codebase, but not compiling... after I ran the debug in visual studio it worked in visual studio AND on the published webpage. sorry for the runaround!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. the problem is in both cases you only see ONE drop down, so running the code will ALWAYS look like the same results.

I mean, your makeup and then this code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Dim intTest As Integer = 2

    If intTest = 1 Then
        DropDownList1.Visible = True
        DropDownList2.Visible = False
    Else
        DropDownList2.Visible = True
        DropDownList1.Visible = False
    End If


End Sub
```

we see this:

[image]

Ok, now we we try this code:

```
    Dim intTest As Integer = 1

    If intTest = 1 Then
        DropDownList1.Visible = True
        DropDownList2.Visible = False
    Else
        DropDownList2.Visible = True
        DropDownList1.Visible = False
    End If
```

So, now we try this with 1, and we see this:

[image]

So, it is working, but the results look 100% the same, since in BOTH cases, we see one drop down. So, how you going to tell if this is REALLY working?

Maybe we should add some text and markup to two boxes, and then we can tell the difference. So your code works - but the screen going to look 100% the SAME in both cases.

lets add some additonal markup, so we can see the difference. Say this:

```
      <div style="height: 318px">

            <div id="drop1" runat="server">
                <h2>This is drop down 1</h2>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="18px" Width="339px" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Choice</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
           </div>

            <div id="drop2" runat="server">
                <h2> This is drop down 2</h2>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="18px" Width="339px" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Choice</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Now, for intTest = 1 we see this:

[image]

And for intTest = 2 we see this:

[image]

And I gave the "div" a "id" and runat = server, so we could do this:

```
    Dim intTest As Integer = 1

    If intTest = 1 Then
        drop1.Visible = True
        drop2.Visible = False
    Else
        drop2.Visible = True
        drop1.Visible = False
    End If
```

And we would see this:

[image]

So, I think your code is working, but with your example markup, you NEVER be able to tell the difference, since in BOTH cases you display one drop down that looks 100% the same in both cases!